# Data Annotation on multiple table in asp.net MVC 2

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, data-annotations

I want to implement data annotation on three tables Link, LinkRef and LinkMeta. Link is main table and other two have LinkId as primary key. Because the system is multi-lingual Link title will be in more than one language so as other details. No of languages will vary. I want to know can i use data annotation in this scenario and if yes then how? Im using Linq2SQL for creating model.

Can Data annotations be applied to class objects?